# AVAudioSession endInterruption() returns an NSOSStatusErrorDomain

Tags: iphone, ios4, avaudiosession

I'm trying to solve an AVAudioSession problem since many hours ago and didn't get success!!

I found lots of guys talking about problems with endInterruption but none of them talking about this error:

```
Unable to reactivate the audio session after the interruption ended: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=560161140 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 560161140.)"
```

I tried converting this code to ASCII to check the Audio Code Results, but there is nothing related to this number.

My code to init the session:

```
- (void) setupAudioSession {

mySession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[mySession setDelegate: self];

NSError *audioSessionError = nil;
[mySession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &audioSessionError];

if (audioSessionError != nil) {
    NSLog (@"Error setting audio session category: %@", [audioSessionError description]);
    return;
}

// Activate the audio session
[mySession setActive: YES error: &audioSessionError];

if (audioSessionError != nil) {
    NSLog (@"Error activating audio session during initial setup: %@", [audioSessionError description]);
    return;
}

// Prepare audio file to play
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL *bgSoundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[mainBundle pathForResource:@"bg_sound" ofType:@"aif"]];

bgPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:bgSoundURL error:&audioSessionError];
if (!bgPlayer) {
    NSLog(@"No bgPlayer: %@", [audioSessionError description]);  
}

[bgPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];
[bgPlayer prepareToPlay];
```

}

And the code of endInterruption method:

```
- (void) endInterruptionWithFlags: (NSUInteger) flags {

if (flags & AVAudioSessionInterruptionFlags_ShouldResume) {

    NSError *endInterruptionError = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &endInterruptionError];
    if (endInterruptionError != nil) {

        NSLog (@"Unable to reactivate the audio session after the interruption ended: %@", [endInterruptionError description]);
        return;

    } else {

        NSLog (@"Audio session reactivated after interruption.");

        if (interruptedWhilePlaying) {

            self.interruptedWhilePlaying = NO;

            // Resume playback by sending a notification to the controller object, which
            //    in turn invokes the playOrStop: toggle method.
            NSString *MixerHostAudioObjectPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification = @"MixerHostAudioObjectPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification";
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: MixerHostAudioObjectPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object: self]; 

        }
    }
}
```

}

A big part of this code was extracted from Apple Mixer Host Sample.
And it's weird that the sample works fine!

Can you guys figure out what is wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem changing the way to design my audio code.
Instead of use AVAudioSession and its delegate methods, I change to the C style to work with audio.

I implemented the function:

```
void interruptionListenerCallback (void *inUserData, UInt32 interruptionState) {}
```

And it was initialized with:

```
AudioSessionInitialize (NULL, NULL, interruptionListenerCallback, self);
```

inside my -(id) init method.

Hope it helps you also.
Best.

Answer (score 2):

> "If this delegate method receives the AVAudioSessionInterruptionFlags_ShouldResume constant in its flags parameter, the audio session is immediately ready to be used."

You didn't handle the callback correctly. When you receive AVAudioSessionInterruptionFlags_ShouldResume, your audio session is ALREADY ready to use. You need to call setActive when you get a DIFFERENT flag.

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

Using @Trinca answer that what I did on "ARC'ed" project:

```
AudioSessionInitialize (NULL, NULL, interruptionListenerCallback, (__bridge void *)(self.player));
```

Were self.player is your player instance that you pass to the callback function.

Then implement the callback:

```
void interruptionListenerCallback (void *inUserData, UInt32 interruptionState) {
   NSLog(@"itnerp state %li",interruptionState);
   NSLog(@"inUserData %@",inUserData);
   AVAudioPlayer *pl = (__bridge AVAudioPlayer*)inUserData;
   switch (interruptionState) {
    case 0:
        [pl play];
    break;

    case 1:
        [pl pause];
    break;
   }

}
```

GOOD LUCK

Shani

Answer (score 0):

use audiosession.setmode if it is voip