# Does not play mp3 file using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I want to play song using AVAudioPlayer. But this is does not work some time. I did not get what is the issue.
I'm using this below  code to play mp3 file from local.

```
NSString *soundFile;
soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"notification_sound" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile];
NSError *error=nil;
self.playerAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &error];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[self.playerAudio setDelegate:self];
NSLog(@"Error:%@",error);
self.playerAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
self.playerAudio.volume=1;
if([self.playerAudio prepareToPlay])
{
    NSLog(@"Prepare to play successfully");
    [self.playerAudio play];
}
```

`if([self.playerAudio prepareToPlay])` this condition never be satisfied why this is happened please help me to solved this issue.

I got this below error : 
**`Error:Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=560557684 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 560557684.)"`**
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using all of those `error` parameters you are setting to `nil` and check the corresponding return values of those methods.

Comment: Why do you require to check [self.playerAudio prepareToPlay] ?
Can't you remove this if condition?

Comment: Can you try adding `NSError *activationError = nil;` to  `self.playerAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&activationError];` and `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error:&activationError];` check the error ?

Comment: @AadilKeshwani : check my updated code.

Comment: Can you put break point in if condition and check if error is still nil ?

Comment: I got this error `Error:Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=560557684 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 560557684.)"`

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/5106895/4321357 might help

Comment: @rmaddy Please check my error and help me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113697/discussion-between-aadil-keshwani-and-monika-patel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution and it is works perfectly :)

```
    NSError *error=nil,*sessionError = nil;
    NSString * soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"notification_sound" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                                     withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers
                                           error:&sessionError];
    if (sessionError) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: setCategory %@", [sessionError localizedDescription]);
    }
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &error];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

    self.playerAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error];

    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &error];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

    [self.playerAudio setDelegate:self];
    self.playerAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
    self.playerAudio.volume=1;
    if([self.playerAudio prepareToPlay])
    {
        [self.playerAudio play];
    }
```

Comment: None of your error checking is correct. For example, it should be: `if (![[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &error]) { NSLog(@"Can't set active: %@", error);`. Never check if the error is set or not. Look at the return value of the method to determine if it succeeded or failed. Then log the error if it failed.