# AVAudioSession error activating: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=561017449: Audio device error on integrating CallKit API to Objective C

Tags: ios, pjsip, callkit

I am developing a VoIP application using [Pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/) in Objective-C.

I want to try and integrate CallKit but I got an error on `configureAudioSession`. I copied `AudioController.h` and `AudioController.mm` from [SpeakerBox from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html) into my project.

And I added this code :

```
 AudioController *audioController;

 - (void)configureAudioSession {
      if (!audioController) {
         audioController = [[AudioController alloc] init];
      }
 }

- (void)handleIncomingCallFrom:(NSString *)dest {
    CXCallUpdate *callUpdate = [[CXCallUpdate alloc] init];
    [callUpdate setLocalizedCallerName:dest];
    [callUpdate setHasVideo:NO];
    CXHandle *calleeHandle = [[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypeGeneric value:dest];
    [callUpdate setRemoteHandle:calleeHandle];
    [provider reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:[NSUUID UUID] update:callUpdate completion:^(NSError *error){
        [self configureAudioSession];
    }];
}
```

Phone is ringing, I can handle the call but it crashes whenever I answer. I receive this error :

```
 AVAudioSession error activating: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=561017449 "(null)"
 2017-03-09 18:17:48.830893 MyVoIPProject[1620:971182] [aurioc] 892: failed: '!pri' (enable 3, outf< 1 ch,  16000 Hz, Int16> inf< 1 ch,  16000 Hz, Int16>)
 2017-03-09 18:17:48.841301 MyVoIPProject[1620:971182] [aurioc] 892: failed: '!pri' (enable 3, outf< 1 ch,  44100 Hz, Int16> inf< 1 ch,  44100 Hz, Int16>)
 2017-03-09 18:17:48.850282 MyVoIPProject[1620:971182] [aurioc] 892: failed: '!pri' (enable 3, outf< 1 ch,  48000 Hz, Int16> inf< 1 ch,  48000 Hz, Int16>)
 .
 .
 .
 .
```

Can you tell me how can I integrate Callkit?

Comment: Relevant: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344403/how-do-i-get-my-sound-to-play-when-a-remote-notification-is-received) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083752/avaudiosession-endinterruption-returns-an-nsosstatuserrordomain) as far as error message is concerned

Comment: I will try. Thanks for answer and editing my question :).

Answer (score -3):

This bug causes by you forget to add the Mircophone description in your Info.plist.

Reference: [SpeakerBox from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html)
[iOS - AudioUnitInitialize returns error code 561017449](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26759942/ios-audiounitinitialize-returns-error-code-561017449)

Comment: No you're wrong, i added Microphone description in my Info.plist

Comment: Hmm, so weird. If you build with your real device, you can check crash log to get more information.